# Show x-axis and y-axis for every plot in facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

As similar question has been asked before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661052/force-x-axis-text-on-for-all-facets-of-a-facet-grid-plot)) but I can't adjust the solution provided there to my specific problem. For every plot shown below, there should be a x as well as y-axis.

The data:

```
df_nSubj <- data.frame(
  nSubj = rep(seq(10L, 50L, by = 10L), each = 24L),
  family = factor(rep(rep(c("AOV", "MLM1", "MLM2", "MLM3"), 5), each = 6L)),
  Spher = factor(rep(rep(c("met", "vio"), 20), each = 3L)),
  effSize = rep(c(0.2, 0.5, 0.8), 40),
  pow = c(
    0.12, 0.53, 0.84, 0.1, 0.4, 0.74, 0.13, 0.55, 0.84, 0.11, 0.44, 0.74, 0.12,
    0.5, 0.82, 0.1, 0.43, 0.76, 0.12, 0.49, 0.81, 0.1, 0.43, 0.76, 0.2, 0.84,
    0.99, 0.15, 0.72, 0.97, 0.21, 0.81, 0.98, 0.17, 0.69, 0.95, 0.2, 0.83, 0.99,
    0.17, 0.75, 0.97, 0.19, 0.82, 0.99, 0.17, 0.75, 0.97, 0.32, 0.95, 1, 0.23,
    0.87, 1, 0.32, 0.92, 1, 0.25, 0.83, 0.99, 0.3, 0.94, 1, 0.24, 0.89, 1, 0.3,
    0.94, 1, 0.24, 0.89, 1, 0.41, 0.99, 1, 0.29, 0.96, 1, 0.4, 0.97, 1, 0.3, 0.92,
    1, 0.38, 0.99, 1, 0.32, 0.97, 1, 0.37, 0.98, 1, 0.32, 0.97, 1, 0.5, 1, 1,
    0.36, 0.98, 1, 0.47, 0.99, 1, 0.36, 0.96, 1, 0.47, 1, 1, 0.4, 0.99, 1, 0.46,
    1, 1, 0.4, 0.99, 1
  )
)
```

plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)
    pl1 <- ggplot(data=df_nSubj,aes(x=nSubj,y=pow,group=family))+
      geom_point(aes(shape=family))+geom_line()+
      labs(x="Number of subjects",y="Power",shape="")+
      scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.2,1),breaks=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1))+
      guides(shape = guide_legend(ncol = 4))+
      facet_grid(Spher~effSize)+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(legend.position = "top",
            panel.margin = unit(2, "lines"),
            legend.key = element_blank(),
            strip.text.x = element_blank(),
            strip.text.y = element_blank(),
            strip.background = element_blank(),
            panel.border=element_blank(),
            axis.line=element_line(),
            axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.5))
```

[image: here's how it looks like]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could do `facet_grid(Spher~effSize, scales = "free")` or maybe `facet_wrap(Spher~effSize, scales = "free")`

Comment: what's wrong with the solution you link to? "I can't adjust [it] to my specific problem" isn't very specific.

Comment: @David no, this doesn't work. at least for me, nothing changes.

Comment: I can't load your data set, I get the error `Error in structure(list(nSubj = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L,  : 
  object 'nSubj' not found` for some reason. Was anyone able to load it?

Comment: @baptiste I cant't copy paste the code provided there since my gtable-structure is not the same. I have to "reorder" it in a different way. Unfortunately, I don't know how.

Comment: @david: now it should work. i created this dataset with dplyr and this might have caused the error.

Comment: @beginneR the general idea is the same, it's just a matter of finding the right indices in the gtable. I've edited my answer to make it slightly more general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change  `facet_grid(Spher~effSize)` to `facet_wrap(Spher~effSize, scales = "free")`

[image]

Comment: Have this functionality disappeared with recent updates?

Comment: Yes, seems this does not work with ggplot version 2.2.1

Comment: There is a solution in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116518/add-x-and-y-axis-to-all-facet-wrap) which works with ggplot 2.2.1, namely to use `annotate()`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm late to this party, but I have two workarounds currently.

The first option is to add horizontal and/or vertical line geoms with intercepts set to -Inf, which requires turning off plot clipping. To the original plot, add the following lines:

```
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=-Inf)) + 
geom_vline(aes(xintercept=-Inf)) + 
coord_cartesian(clip="off")
```

**Fake Axis Option**
[image]

Alternatively, use the lemon package and its facet command. This will reproduce the axes and their ticks without adding the labels.

```
library(lemon)
```

And change `facet_grid(Spher~effSize)` to `facet_rep_grid(Spher~effSize)`

**Lemon Package Option**
[image]

Comment: I used this approach and like it because sometimes you want the axis lines for visual appeal, but don't need the tick labels to be repeated.

Answer (score 4):

The [`ggh4x` package](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html) also has this functionality via its `facet_wrap2` function

[image: ggh4x facet_wrap2 function]