# How to increse axis line width in ggplot2 facet plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, width, facet

How do I increase x axis line width also for individual plots 1, 2 and 3, and y axis for 2, 3, 6 and 8?
Thanks

```
mtcars %>%
    rownames_to_column('car') %>%
    tidyr::gather(variable, value, disp:hp, -carb, factor_key = TRUE) %>%

    ggplot(aes(variable, value)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, width = 0.5) +
    geom_jitter(width = 0.2, size = 1, alpha = 0.7) +
    facet_wrap( ~ carb) +
    theme(axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: How about y-axis for 2,3,6,8?

Comment: Let us know if linked post helps.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! Could not find this! This one https://stackoverflow.com/a/49386298/5575616 worked good for me.