# Ggplot2: scales="free_y" but keeping x axis line

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sorry if this is too basic, but if anyone can guide me to a solution, it would be great.

I have a plot with 5 separate charts and I'm using scales="free_y". Is there a way to keep just the horizontal line for x axis label for each of the 4 charts above?

```
df <- data_frame(ReqID = 100, ID_Seq = 1:5, Created = dmy("01/01/2018","10/02/2018","18/03/2018", "22/04/2018", "18/05/2018"), fruits = c("Apple","Banana", "Blueberry", "Avocado", "Grapes"))


df <- df %>%
  group_by(ReqID) %>% 
  complete(Created = seq.Date(min(Created),max(Created), by = "day")) %>%
  fill(ReqID,ID_Seq,fruits)

df$counts <- seq.int(nrow(df))

fruits <- ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=Created,y=counts,fill=fruits),
           stat = "identity",
           width = 1) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 days", date_labels = "%b-%d",
               limits = c(min(df$Created),max(df$Created)+1),
               expand = c(0,0),
               name = "Date") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,max(df$counts)*1.01),
                     expand = c(0,0),
                     name = "Fruits") +
  facet_wrap(fruits ~ ., scales = "free_y", nrow = 5) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        legend.position = "bottom",  legend.justification = "center", axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),

        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = element_blank(),
                    values = c("#BFBFBF","#99CCFF",
                               "#BFBFBF","#CCE5FF",
                               "#CCCFFF"))

fruits
```

Comment: (1) Replace `"free_y"` with either `"free_x"` or `"free"`. (2) The use of `limits` *appears* to be overriding your `scales=` argument; if you remove `limits=` then it works (I think) as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

I added a geom_segment, as per this answer here:
[Add x and y axis to all facet_wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116518/add-x-and-y-axis-to-all-facet-wrap)

[Your desired plots with x axis lines (code output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr9j6.png)

(I also swapped df with df_ )

```
df_ <- data.frame(ReqID = 100, ID_Seq = 1:5, Created = dmy("01/01/2018","10/02/2018","18/03/2018", "22/04/2018", "18/05/2018"), fruits = c("Apple","Banana", "Blueberry", "Avocado", "Grapes"))


df_ <- df_ %>%
    group_by(ReqID) %>% 
    complete(Created = seq.Date(min(Created),max(Created), by = "day")) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    fill(ReqID,ID_Seq,fruits)

df_$counts <- seq.int(nrow(df_))

fruits <- ggplot(data = df_) +
    geom_bar(aes(x=Created,y=counts,fill=fruits),
             stat = "identity",
             width = 1) +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 days", date_labels = "%b-%d",
                 limits = c(min(df_$Created),max(df_$Created)+1),
                 expand = c(0,0),
                 name = "Date") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,max(df_$counts)*1.01),
                       expand = c(0,0),
                       name = "Fruits")  +
    theme(axis.line = element_line()) +
    facet_wrap(fruits ~ ., scales = "free_y", nrow = 5) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
          legend.position = "bottom",  legend.justification = "center", axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),

          strip.background = element_blank(),
          strip.text = element_blank()) +
    scale_fill_manual(name = element_blank(),
                      values = c("#BFBFBF","#99CCFF",
                                 "#BFBFBF","#CCE5FF",
                                 "#CCCFFF"))  +
    annotate("segment", x=min(df_$Created), xend=max(df_$Created), y=-Inf, yend=-Inf)

fruits
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!