# Add ticks without labels on the top of a bar plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

As the title says, I would like to add ticks to the TOP part of the bar plot in ggplot2. The output would look something like this: (hiding the actual plot due to confidential information). Is there a function in ggplot2 that does this?

[image: example bar plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adapted Baptiste's solution at link [Display y-axis for each subplot when faceting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987834/display-y-axis-for-each-subplot-when-faceting/21994581#21994581). Idea (i think) is to extract the x-axis grob and add it to the top of the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)

# plot
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) + geom_bar() + theme_bw()


gg <- ggplotGrob(p1)

axis <- gtable_filter(gg ,"axis-b")[["grobs"]][[1]][["children"]][["axis"]][1,]
panels <- subset(gg$layout, name == "panel")
gg <- gtable_add_grob(gg, grobs=axis, name="ticks", t = panels$t-1, l=panels$l)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gg)
```

[image]